# Book section in the ref.bib file

Tags: r-markdown

I am looking for the solution on how I must describe the book section in the ref.bib file so that in my Markdown pdf file the References section contained this, for example:

> Early B.E. (2021). Making sanctions work: promoting compliance, punishing violations, and
> discouraging sanctions busting. In Peter A.G. van Bergeijk (Ed.), *Research Handbook on
> Economic Sanctions* (pp. 167-187). Edward Elgar Publishing.

My current knowledge of Markdown yields just this syntax:

```
@book{sanctions2021,
    title  = {Making sanctions work: promoting compliance, punishing violations, and 
              discouraging sanctions busting},
    author = {Bryan R. Early},
    year   = {2021},
    publisher = {Edward Elgar Publishing},
    pages  = {167--187}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the current and expected result?

Comment: Currently it yields this: Early, B. R. (2021). _Making sanctions work: Promoting compliance, punishing violations, and discouraging sanctions busting_ (pp. 167–187). Edward Elgar Publishing.

Comment: Expected: Early B.E. (2021). Making sanctions work: promoting compliance, punishing violations, and discouraging sanctions busting. In Peter A.G. van Bergeijk (Ed.), _Research Handbook on Economic Sanctions_ (pp. 167-187). Edward Elgar Publishing.

Comment: Thanks for the expected result, tried again and updated my answer below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bibliography.html

> Items can be cited directly within the documentation using the syntax @key where key is the citation key in the first line of the entry, e.g., @R-base. To put citations in parentheses, use [@key]. To cite multiple entries, separate the keys by semicolons, e.g., [@key-1; @key-2; @key-3]. To suppress the mention of the author, add a minus sign before @, e.g., [-@R-base].

and this example:

```
@Manual{R-base,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical
           Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2019},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org},
}
```

You need to use a CSL (Citation Style Language) file.

From: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bibliography.html#bibliography

> By default, Pandoc will use a Chicago author-date format for citations and references. To use another style, you will need to specify a CSL (Citation Style Language) file in the csl metadata field.

According to the docs, CSL files can be tweaked to meet custom formatting requirements. The XML formats of the CSL files make it hard to edit them manually.

I tried the mentioned visual editor https://editor.citationstyles.org but I got a bit lost... It seems that you can:

1. load a style that matches yours. I have tried https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=Chicago&format=author-date.
2. edit a style by clicking the single text elements in the example at the top. I have quickly tried to change some italic formatting and remove some brackets.
3. save/download the style.